# SDWebImage 5.0 getting crashed when loading image in UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, sdwebimage

I have 2 separate UICollectionView in my ViewController, I am trying to use the below code to load the images from URLs. To cache image and load it in asynchronous I started using SDWebImage 5.0 through cocoa pods. But my app getting crashed with the below message. I have tried previous versions of SDWebImage and still having this issue. I even added -ObjC flag in other linked flags :

```
 -[UIImageView sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x143d05420
2019-12-28 12:12:48.436501+0530 BlondWaves[6037:907402] TIC Read Status [1:0x0]: 1:57
2019-12-28 12:12:48.438329+0530 BlondWaves[6037:907224] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIImageView sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x143d05420'

*** First throw call stack:

(0x1fc02f180 0x1fb2079f8 0x1fbf4b9bc 0x22868e220 0x1fc0349c8 0x1fc03665c 0x100f1b070 0x227f54e44 0x227f58efc 0x227f5d8bc 0x228afa170 0x20056cc60 0x200571c08 0x2004d43e4 0x200502620 0x22865c7e0 0x228745408 0x22873e330 0x1fbfc0f1c 0x1fbfc0e9c 0x1fbfc07d4 0x1fbfbb6c0 0x1fbfbafb4 0x1fe1bc79c 0x228662c38 0x100f1d4f0 0x1fba7e8e0)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Here is my UICollectionView Code :

```
    //loading featured collection data
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if(collectionView == self.collectionView){
        return _resultArray.count;
    }else{
        return _resultArray.count;
    }
}


- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(collectionView == self.collectionView){
        NSString *urlString = [[_resultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"url"];
        NSLog(@"%@",urlString);

        featuredCell *cell =[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

       [cell.photo sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
        placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];

        return cell;
    }else{
        NSString *urlString = [[_userArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"url"];
        NSLog(@"%@",urlString);

        userCell *cell =[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"user" forIndexPath:indexPath];
       [cell.userphoto sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]
              placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
        return cell;
    }

}
```

Comment: try to clean your project, I don't have any problems with your code

Comment: There is a high chance that the url received might be empty or doesn't follow right pattern http(s)://xxxx.xx. I this is not followed, NSURL might be empty. So you can add a check for NSURL before passing to ImageWithURL

Comment: Can you reproduce it after you clean the project?